# routing all aspx pages at once in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to write a single line of code so as to route all .aspx files in my webform application. Currently, i have to create an individual lines of code to tackle for each pages. Is there a way to do achieve this in a single code? Here is what i have been doing to each page.

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("dealerinforoute", "DealerInfo", "~/DealerInfo.aspx");
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("defaultroute", "Home", "~/Default.aspx");
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("orderroute", "Order", "~/Order.aspx");
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("addplanroute", "AddPlan", "~/AddPlan.aspx");
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("dealerTagroute", "DealerTag", "~/DealerTag.aspx");
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("proofroute", "Proof", "~/Proof.aspx");
```

I was wondering if I could do something like

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("routeaspxfiles", "/{pg}", "~/*.aspx");
```

Even when i try to use the code above, it erros out. Please advise if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add routing rules to you global.asax file inside of Application_Start method

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 // Code that runs on application startup
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute",
  "BookStore/{Name}",
 "~/Webpages/BookStore/ViewBookDemo.aspx");
 }
```